# Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\couriermanagement\database.php on line 15

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the `database.php` code every time I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: dbConn in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\couriermanagement\database.php on line 15
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\couriermanagement\database.php on line 15
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\couriermanagement\database.php on line 15

```
<?php


// database connection config
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUser = 'root';
$dbPass = '';
$dbName = 'courier_db';

 $dbConn = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName) or die ('MySQL 
 connect failed. ' . mysqli_error($dbConn));
//mysqli_select_db($dbConn ,$dbName) or die('Cannot select database. ' . 
  mysqli_error($dbConn));//

 function dbQuery($sql)
{
$result = mysqli_query($dbConn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

return $result;
}

function dbAffectedRows()
{
global $dbConn;

return mysqli_affected_rows($dbConn);
 }

 function dbFetchArray($result, $resultType = MYSQL_NUM) {
return mysqli_fetch_array($result, $resultType);
 }

 function dbFetchAssoc($result)
{
return mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}

 function dbFetchRow($result) 
{
return mysqli_fetch_row($result);
}

 function dbFreeResult($result)
 {
return mysqli_free_result($result);
 }

 function dbNumRows($result)
 {
return mysqli_num_rows($result);
 }

 function dbSelect($dbName)
 {
    return mysqli_select_db($dbName);
 }

 function dbInsertId()
  {
  return mysqli_insert_id();
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: You have to supply two parameters , one for query and another for  connection in mysqli_query($query,$conn)

Comment: Either way you can call the query $result = mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql)  Add connection to query  or $result = $dbConn->query($sql); [Check the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: $result = $dbConn->query($sql);  used this one but still getting error 
             Notice: Undefined variable: dbConn in C:\xampp\htdocs\couriermanagement\database.php on line 15

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function mysqli_query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\couriermanagement\database.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\couriermanagement\login.php(13): dbQuery('SELECT DISTINCT...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\couriermanagement\database.php on line 15

Answer (score 1):

The "link" is missing i think you upgrade from mysql to mysqli

it should look like this:

```
$dbConn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
mysqli_query($dbConn, "SELECT * FROM test");
```

read:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

under Procedural style

Comment: i have used $dbconn still getting error undefined variable

Comment: function dbQuery($sql) { global $dbconn; $result = mysqli_query($dbConn,$sql); } because try to access the variable which not defined in the function

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
$con=mysqli_connect("hostmane","userename","password","db_name");
```

before the line

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbConn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: You have an error. `mysqli_error()` needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)